# jQuery - How to create a new function to simulate document.ready on ajaxComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am using the **FoundationPress** theme (Wordpress Theme with the Foundation 6 from Zurb framework), and i'd like to ajaxify it. (using Ajaxify Wordpress Site plugin).

Now my problem is that most of the javascript that's on my website isn't working after an ajax load.

I have found that this is because *most of the javascript in the foundation.js file is executed on* `document.ready`, and that this event is *not being triggered when loading a page with ajax*.

I understand that it is not possible to trigger the `document.ready` event after page load. And after seeing multiple threads here, it appears the only solution is to create a new function with the code that's needed on `document.ready` and ajaxComplete.

BUT, Foundation has a lot of javascript files, and most of it is above my level of understanding. Is there any way to create a function that would automate this ?

---

EDIT 
 I tried this. I need to pass jQuery as an argument or the code inside `initialiseSticky` will not work. It works for `document.ready` but not for `ajaxComplete`, any idea ?

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    console.log('document ready- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function ($) {
    console.log('ajax complete- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);

}(jQuery));

function initialiseSticky($) {
//my code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about foundation.js but if you can make a variable, **`FooBar`** for example,  assign the `function()` in `$(document).ready()` to that variable, and then on ajaxComplete call the variable/function again to "re-trigger" it, like below:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kLx8xw02/3/)

```js
var res = $('#result'),
  bg = $('#bg-div'),
  btn = $('#btnTest'),
  i = 0, // just for demo to illustrate that it is changing
  FooBar;

$(document).ready(FooBar = function() {
  bg.delay(200).fadeIn(2000);
  console.log('document is ready ' + i++);
});

// simulate ajaxComplete 
btn.on('click', function() {
  res.text('just dummy text here ' + i);
  bg.fadeOut(500);
  FooBar();
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#bg-div { background-color: orange; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: -1; display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg-div"></div>
<button id="btnTest">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! My functions are written like this : !function ($) {}(jQuery), and i assume this is Foundation's way of saying document.ready. how can I add the variable/function to that ?
Also, isn't it dangerous to reload all of the code a second time ?

Comment: Well, it is not dangerous to load it twice, or more, it is just not dangerous but it is could be inefficient and redundant, depending on what's inside the `.ready` function in **foundation.js** and what part of the code you want to execute twice or more.

Comment: Of course it is better to wrap only the part of code you want to trigger again on ajaxComplete inside a function, as you said in the question "*create a new function with the code that's needed on `document.ready` and ajaxComplete*" but again it depends on how that part of code is written, this is one of the main reasons I don't prefer working with frameworks like bootstrap, foundation, etc

Comment: Yes exactly ! Thanks for your answer :) I'm going to load only the bit of code I need to! I opened a new topic because i'm running into a problem with that code syntax : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332253/how-to-pass-the-jquery-element-inside-a-function-syntax?noredirect=1#comment75669482_44332253 :)

Comment: check [**this jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kLx8xw02/4/) I am using same technique as in the answer but only repeating portion of code