# How to pass the jQuery element inside a function - syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation-6

I need to pass jQuery as an argument in the first two functions, or the code inside `initialiseSticky` will not work. 
It does work for `document.ready` but not for `ajaxComplete`, my syntax is probably not good at all...

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    console.log('document ready- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function ($) {
    console.log('ajax complete- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);

}(jQuery));

function initialiseSticky($) {
//my code
}
```

---

Before I edited, the function with all the code below looked like this :

```
!function ($) {
    //my code (now initialiseSticky function)
}(jQuery)
```

---

EDIT : I don't know if that will help, but here is the website where this issue is : http://lesdeuxvagues.com/demo look at the menu and it's sticky state. So far, it works on normal page load but not with ajax.

---

EDIT 2 : 
Here's the rest of the code :

```
function initialiseSticky($) {

    console.log('initialise- sticky');
/**
 * Sticky module.
 * @module foundation.sticky
 * @requires foundation.util.triggers
 * @requires foundation.util.mediaQuery
 */

class Sticky {
  /**
   * Creates a new instance of a sticky thing.
   * @class
   * @param {jQuery} element - jQuery object to make sticky.
   * @param {Object} options - options object passed when creating the element programmatically.
   */
  constructor(element, options) {
    this.$element = element;
    this.options = $.extend({}, Sticky.defaults, this.$element.data(), options);

    this._init();

    Foundation.registerPlugin(this, 'Sticky');
  }

  /**
   * Initializes the sticky element by adding classes, getting/setting dimensions, breakpoints and attributes
   * @function
   * @private
   */
  _init() {
    var $parent = this.$element.parent('[data-sticky-container]'),
        id = this.$element[0].id || Foundation.GetYoDigits(6, 'sticky'),
        _this = this;

    if (!$parent.length) {
      this.wasWrapped = true;
    }
    this.$container = $parent.length ? $parent : $(this.options.container).wrapInner(this.$element);
    this.$container.addClass(this.options.containerClass);

    this.$element.addClass(this.options.stickyClass).attr({ 'data-resize': id, 'data-mutate': id });
    if (this.options.anchor !== '') {
        $('#' + _this.options.anchor).attr({ 'data-mutate': id });
    }

    this.scrollCount = this.options.checkEvery;
    this.isStuck = false;
    $(window).one('load.zf.sticky', function(){
      //We calculate the container height to have correct values for anchor points offset calculation.
      _this.containerHeight = _this.$element.css("display") == "none" ? 0 : _this.$element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
      _this.$container.css('height', _this.containerHeight);
      _this.elemHeight = _this.containerHeight;
      if(_this.options.anchor !== ''){
        _this.$anchor = $('#' + _this.options.anchor);
      }else{
        _this._parsePoints();
      }

      _this._setSizes(function(){
        var scroll = window.pageYOffset;
        _this._calc(false, scroll);
        //Unstick the element will ensure that proper classes are set.
        if (!_this.isStuck) {
          _this._removeSticky((scroll >= _this.topPoint) ? false : true);
        }
      });
      _this._events(id.split('-').reverse().join('-'));
    });
  }

  /**
   * If using multiple elements as anchors, calculates the top and bottom pixel values the sticky thing should stick and unstick on.
   * @function
   * @private
   */
  _parsePoints() {
    var top = this.options.topAnchor == "" ? 1 : this.options.topAnchor,
        btm = this.options.btmAnchor== "" ? document.documentElement.scrollHeight : this.options.btmAnchor,
        pts = [top, btm],
        breaks = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = pts.length; i < len && pts[i]; i++) {
      var pt;
      if (typeof pts[i] === 'number') {
        pt = pts[i];
      } else {
        var place = pts[i].split(':'),
            anchor = $(`#${place[0]}`);

        pt = anchor.offset().top;
        if (place[1] && place[1].toLowerCase() === 'bottom') {
          pt += anchor[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
        }
      }
      breaks[i] = pt;
    }


    this.points = breaks;
    return;
  }

  /**
   * Adds event handlers for the scrolling element.
   * @private
   * @param {String} id - psuedo-random id for unique scroll event listener.
   */
  _events(id) {
    var _this = this,
        scrollListener = this.scrollListener = `scroll.zf.${id}`;
    if (this.isOn) { return; }
    if (this.canStick) {
      this.isOn = true;
      $(window).off(scrollListener)
               .on(scrollListener, function(e) {
                 if (_this.scrollCount === 0) {
                   _this.scrollCount = _this.options.checkEvery;
                   _this._setSizes(function() {
                     _this._calc(false, window.pageYOffset);
                   });
                 } else {
                   _this.scrollCount--;
                   _this._calc(false, window.pageYOffset);
                 }
              });
    }

    this.$element.off('resizeme.zf.trigger')
                 .on('resizeme.zf.trigger', function(e, el) {
                    _this._eventsHandler(id);
    });

    this.$element.on('mutateme.zf.trigger', function (e, el) {
        _this._eventsHandler(id);
    });

    if(this.$anchor) {
      this.$anchor.on('mutateme.zf.trigger', function (e, el) {
          _this._eventsHandler(id);
      });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handler for events.
   * @private
   * @param {String} id - psuedo-random id for unique scroll event listener.
   */
  _eventsHandler(id) {
       var _this = this,
        scrollListener = this.scrollListener = `scroll.zf.${id}`;

       _this._setSizes(function() {
       _this._calc(false);
       if (_this.canStick) {
         if (!_this.isOn) {
           _this._events(id);
         }
       } else if (_this.isOn) {
         _this._pauseListeners(scrollListener);
       }
     });
  }

  /**
   * Removes event handlers for scroll and change events on anchor.
   * @fires Sticky#pause
   * @param {String} scrollListener - unique, namespaced scroll listener attached to `window`
   */
  _pauseListeners(scrollListener) {
    this.isOn = false;
    $(window).off(scrollListener);

    /**
     * Fires when the plugin is paused due to resize event shrinking the view.
     * @event Sticky#pause
     * @private
     */
     this.$element.trigger('pause.zf.sticky');
  }

  /**
   * Called on every `scroll` event and on `_init`
   * fires functions based on booleans and cached values
   * @param {Boolean} checkSizes - true if plugin should recalculate sizes and breakpoints.
   * @param {Number} scroll - current scroll position passed from scroll event cb function. If not passed, defaults to `window.pageYOffset`.
   */
  _calc(checkSizes, scroll) {
    if (checkSizes) { this._setSizes(); }

    if (!this.canStick) {
      if (this.isStuck) {
        this._removeSticky(true);
      }
      return false;
    }

    if (!scroll) { scroll = window.pageYOffset; }

    if (scroll >= this.topPoint) {
      if (scroll <= this.bottomPoint) {
        if (!this.isStuck) {
          this._setSticky();
        }
      } else {
        if (this.isStuck) {
          this._removeSticky(false);
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (this.isStuck) {
        this._removeSticky(true);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Causes the $element to become stuck.
   * Adds `position: fixed;`, and helper classes.
   * @fires Sticky#stuckto
   * @function
   * @private
   */
  _setSticky() {
    var _this = this,
        stickTo = this.options.stickTo,
        mrgn = stickTo === 'top' ? 'marginTop' : 'marginBottom',
        notStuckTo = stickTo === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top',
        css = {};

    css[mrgn] = `${this.options[mrgn]}em`;
    css[stickTo] = 0;
    css[notStuckTo] = 'auto';
    this.isStuck = true;
    this.$element.removeClass(`is-anchored is-at-${notStuckTo}`)
                 .addClass(`is-stuck is-at-${stickTo}`)
                 .css(css)
                 /**
                  * Fires when the $element has become `position: fixed;`
                  * Namespaced to `top` or `bottom`, e.g. `sticky.zf.stuckto:top`
                  * @event Sticky#stuckto
                  */
                 .trigger(`sticky.zf.stuckto:${stickTo}`);
    this.$element.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function() {
      _this._setSizes();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Causes the $element to become unstuck.
   * Removes `position: fixed;`, and helper classes.
   * Adds other helper classes.
   * @param {Boolean} isTop - tells the function if the $element should anchor to the top or bottom of its $anchor element.
   * @fires Sticky#unstuckfrom
   * @private
   */
  _removeSticky(isTop) {
    var stickTo = this.options.stickTo,
        stickToTop = stickTo === 'top',
        css = {},
        anchorPt = (this.points ? this.points[1] - this.points[0] : this.anchorHeight) - this.elemHeight,
        mrgn = stickToTop ? 'marginTop' : 'marginBottom',
        notStuckTo = stickToTop ? 'bottom' : 'top',
        topOrBottom = isTop ? 'top' : 'bottom';

    css[mrgn] = 0;

    css['bottom'] = 'auto';
    if(isTop) {
      css['top'] = 0;
    } else {
      css['top'] = anchorPt;
    }

    this.isStuck = false;
    this.$element.removeClass(`is-stuck is-at-${stickTo}`)
                 .addClass(`is-anchored is-at-${topOrBottom}`)
                 .css(css)
                 /**
                  * Fires when the $element has become anchored.
                  * Namespaced to `top` or `bottom`, e.g. `sticky.zf.unstuckfrom:bottom`
                  * @event Sticky#unstuckfrom
                  */
                 .trigger(`sticky.zf.unstuckfrom:${topOrBottom}`);
  }

  /**
   * Sets the $element and $container sizes for plugin.
   * Calls `_setBreakPoints`.
   * @param {Function} cb - optional callback function to fire on completion of `_setBreakPoints`.
   * @private
   */
  _setSizes(cb) {
    this.canStick = Foundation.MediaQuery.is(this.options.stickyOn);
    if (!this.canStick) {
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') { cb(); }
    }
    var _this = this,
        newElemWidth = this.$container[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
        comp = window.getComputedStyle(this.$container[0]),
        pdngl = parseInt(comp['padding-left'], 10),
        pdngr = parseInt(comp['padding-right'], 10);

    if (this.$anchor && this.$anchor.length) {
      this.anchorHeight = this.$anchor[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    } else {
      this._parsePoints();
    }

    this.$element.css({
      'max-width': `${newElemWidth - pdngl - pdngr}px`
    });

    var newContainerHeight = this.$element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height || this.containerHeight;
    if (this.$element.css("display") == "none") {
      newContainerHeight = 0;
    }
    this.containerHeight = newContainerHeight;
    this.$container.css({
      height: newContainerHeight
    });
    this.elemHeight = newContainerHeight;

    if (!this.isStuck) {
      if (this.$element.hasClass('is-at-bottom')) {
        var anchorPt = (this.points ? this.points[1] - this.$container.offset().top : this.anchorHeight) - this.elemHeight;
        this.$element.css('top', anchorPt);
      }
    }

    this._setBreakPoints(newContainerHeight, function() {
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') { cb(); }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Sets the upper and lower breakpoints for the element to become sticky/unsticky.
   * @param {Number} elemHeight - px value for sticky.$element height, calculated by `_setSizes`.
   * @param {Function} cb - optional callback function to be called on completion.
   * @private
   */
  _setBreakPoints(elemHeight, cb) {
    if (!this.canStick) {
      if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') { cb(); }
      else { return false; }
    }
    var mTop = emCalc(this.options.marginTop),
        mBtm = emCalc(this.options.marginBottom),
        topPoint = this.points ? this.points[0] : this.$anchor.offset().top,
        bottomPoint = this.points ? this.points[1] : topPoint + this.anchorHeight,
        // topPoint = this.$anchor.offset().top || this.points[0],
        // bottomPoint = topPoint + this.anchorHeight || this.points[1],
        winHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (this.options.stickTo === 'top') {
      topPoint -= mTop;
      bottomPoint -= (elemHeight + mTop);
    } else if (this.options.stickTo === 'bottom') {
      topPoint -= (winHeight - (elemHeight + mBtm));
      bottomPoint -= (winHeight - mBtm);
    } else {
      //this would be the stickTo: both option... tricky
    }

    this.topPoint = topPoint;
    this.bottomPoint = bottomPoint;

    if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') { cb(); }
  }

  /**
   * Destroys the current sticky element.
   * Resets the element to the top position first.
   * Removes event listeners, JS-added css properties and classes, and unwraps the $element if the JS added the $container.
   * @function
   */
  destroy() {
    this._removeSticky(true);

    this.$element.removeClass(`${this.options.stickyClass} is-anchored is-at-top`)
                 .css({
                   height: '',
                   top: '',
                   bottom: '',
                   'max-width': ''
                 })
                 .off('resizeme.zf.trigger')
                 .off('mutateme.zf.trigger');
    if (this.$anchor && this.$anchor.length) {
      this.$anchor.off('change.zf.sticky');
    }
    $(window).off(this.scrollListener);

    if (this.wasWrapped) {
      this.$element.unwrap();
    } else {
      this.$container.removeClass(this.options.containerClass)
                     .css({
                       height: ''
                     });
    }
    Foundation.unregisterPlugin(this);
  }
}

Sticky.defaults = {
  /**
   * Customizable container template. Add your own classes for styling and sizing.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default '&lt;div data-sticky-container&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'
   */
  container: '<div data-sticky-container></div>',
  /**
   * Location in the view the element sticks to. Can be `'top'` or `'bottom'`.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default 'top'
   */
  stickTo: 'top',
  /**
   * If anchored to a single element, the id of that element.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default ''
   */
  anchor: '',
  /**
   * If using more than one element as anchor points, the id of the top anchor.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default ''
   */
  topAnchor: '',
  /**
   * If using more than one element as anchor points, the id of the bottom anchor.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default ''
   */
  btmAnchor: '',
  /**
   * Margin, in `em`'s to apply to the top of the element when it becomes sticky.
   * @option
   * @type {number}
   * @default 1
   */
  marginTop: 1,
  /**
   * Margin, in `em`'s to apply to the bottom of the element when it becomes sticky.
   * @option
   * @type {number}
   * @default 1
   */
  marginBottom: 1,
  /**
   * Breakpoint string that is the minimum screen size an element should become sticky.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default 'medium'
   */
  stickyOn: 'medium',
  /**
   * Class applied to sticky element, and removed on destruction. Foundation defaults to `sticky`.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default 'sticky'
   */
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  /**
   * Class applied to sticky container. Foundation defaults to `sticky-container`.
   * @option
   * @type {string}
   * @default 'sticky-container'
   */
  containerClass: 'sticky-container',
  /**
   * Number of scroll events between the plugin's recalculating sticky points. Setting it to `0` will cause it to recalc every scroll event, setting it to `-1` will prevent recalc on scroll.
   * @option
   * @type {number}
   * @default -1
   */
  checkEvery: -1
};

/**
 * Helper function to calculate em values
 * @param Number {em} - number of em's to calculate into pixels
 */
function emCalc(em) {
  return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).fontSize, 10) * em;
}

// Window exports
Foundation.plugin(Sticky, 'Sticky');

}
```

Comment: The first function is called when the document is ready, but nothing is passed so $ is undefined. The second one is executed immediately, which is probably also not what you want. Why do you need to explicitly pass jQuery as $ here?

Comment: I need the code inside initialiseSticky to run when the document is ready, and also after an ajax reload. The code inside, which was not written by me, uses "this" in reference to $, the jQuery object or something, which is why I need to pass it ! I'm not sure I understand why $ is undefined, forgive me, my understanding of jquery is pretty basic

Comment: Why do you need to pass jquery to the function it should be available gobally?

Comment: `(function ($){ $(document).ajaxComplete(...)) })(jQuery)` ?

Comment: I just realized. The this is used inside `class Sticky { //here }`. So I'm not even sure... I don't understand why it works with the first function (`document.ready`) and not with the second (`ajaxComplete`)...

Comment: because with your `function ($) {
    console.log('ajax complete- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
}(jQuery)` construct nothing gets passed to the ajaxComplete callback, its an immediatly executed function which doesn't return anything making it like `$(document).ajaxComplete(null);`

Comment: @xDreamCoding Pretty sure thats a syntax error too

Comment: @xDreamCoding ok! Do you know how I could fix this syntax error ?

Comment: If jQuery is accessed as `this` in that function you need to pass `initialiseSticky.bind(jQuery)`. This returns a new function with the `this` value set to jQuery

Comment: When I go to your demo page, it seems to be calling `initialise- sticky` after `ajax complete- sticky` so I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks yes it does! But the code inside the function (I edited my question with it) isn't working. It's making the menu stick on scroll down..

Comment: What are you expecting the menu to do?

Comment: The menu is supposed to be sticky when scrolling down (which it is, just not on ajax load). On the homepage, it's transparent and then when it's sticky it's white. (but this is css) I'm trying to find how to make the code work both on regular page load and on ajax load (when a link is clicked)

Comment: I edited what the function looked liked before !

Answer (score 1):

Javascript implements [`Closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) so any **`inner function`** is able to visit the parent scope.

```js
var foo = 'bar';

function baz() {
  console.log(foo); // => baz
}
```

Now, because your `initialiseSticky` is an inner function of the *global scope* **`Window`** and also `jQuery` is in this scope as `window.jQuery` you don't need to pass a jQuery reference to `initialiseSticky` because it is already able to access it.

note that `$` is just an alias of `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code is messed around a lot. I'll try to strip it down.

```
$(function() { 
    console.log('document ready- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    console.log('ajax complete- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
});

function initialiseSticky($) {
//my code
}
```

Try if this works. Note: I'm not sure passing $ is even necessary.

Comment: Believe it or not, this is actually exactly what my first try looked like, but I have no idea why, it worked for the document.ready only when I added this : `jQuery(function($) { 
    console.log('document ready- sticky');
    initialiseSticky($);
});` But it still wouldn't work with ajaxComplete. I'm really lost as to why it works in document.ready...